# rear wheel spin on motorcycle

Tags: motorcycle, clutch

With my bike on a paddok stand and turned on,
I know the rear wheel spins in neutral but when I put it in gear and pull the clutch lever in it still continues to spin.
**Now the question is** I can stop the wheel with my hand or foot but the wheel feels like it wants to pull, this is still in gear with the clutch in, if I let go of the wheel it will spin again with the lever in. Is this normal?

Comment: I'll let a more qualified person "answer" but I think the wet clutch in a motorcycle is always going to tug the rear wheel a little when the clutch is in because of the oil viscosity.

Comment: post as an answer - gets my vote...

Comment: How do I post as answer? That does make sense with it being a wet clutch.

Answer (score 1):

JPhi1618 is right in the comments. Its the hydraulic drag created by the oil between the gears in the gearbox causing the wheel rotation. This is very normal for bikes having wet clutch.